# What is diffrence between Energy measurement ADC and Bridge Sensor ADC?

Tags: sensor, adc, bridge

What is diffrence between Energy measurement ADC and Bridge Sensor ADC. I came across many ADC. One such example is microchip MCP3901. This is an energy measurement ADC. Can i use it for Bridge Sensor application? And Analog device has many bridge sensor ADC like AD7796 ,AD7901 etc. Could anyone tell what is the difference in these two ADC.

Comment: why would you think an energy measurement adc is even remotely related to a bridge sensor adc? These are two wildly different applications!

Answer (score 3):

Both the MCP3901 and the AD7796 are sophisticated ADCs but the first thing that marks the difference to me is that the microchip device performs synchronous sampling to ensure that when the two channels are digitized, they are "captured" at the same point in time. This is important for when used in energy management because voltage and current waveforms need to be multiplied together to calculate power and if there is a timing difference there will be a power error.

The AD7796 is just a single channel device with on-board temperature digitization and fixed analog gain of 128 making it suitable for bridge sensing. The MCP3901 has a much faster sampling speed capability making it suitable for a wider range of input signals and in particular for sampling "current" waveforms that may have many high order harmonics that must not be aliased because this can cause other "power calc" problems.

The MCP3901 also has a programmable gain amplifier whereas the AD part is fixed.

The two devices have different target applications and the microchip part potentially has the capability of performing bridge sensor digitization except it won't have the dc accuracy needed on sensitive applications.

The AD part also requires an external reference voltage and this can be chosen to be very accurate (at some cost obviously) whereas the Microchip part has a rather inaccurate internal reference but it can be overridden with an external reference.

The two devices are similar on the face of it but the devil is in the detail.

Comment: @ Andy aka Thanks for youy reply. What do you mean by  " it won't have the dc accuracy needed on sensitive applications."

Comment: @abhilash Because the microchip device is targeted at energy measurement, dc offsets have no implication on calculation of power because the two signals being measured are AC voltage and current. This means it doesn't have to control dc offsets unlike the AD part - it has to be very accurate with dc offset drift because it is intended to be measuring dc signals.

Comment: +1, excellent breakdown of the distinction between the two devices.